# How to vary the inputs of a function until the function returns a specific value

Tags: python, function, loops, optimization

So I have a function that has four inputs and returns three outputs. I am trying to find the minimum value of the main variable, "a", for which the secondary variables, "b" and "c", meet certain constraints.

I have found the minimum value for a, when given varying inputs by using baysian optimization, but I am struggling to figure out how to make that minimum value meet the constraints. One idea I had was to vary or "shake" the four inputs by small increments so that the main variable does not move much from its local minimum, but slides up the slope a little on each side until the constraints for b and c are met.

The code below shows the inputs that I have found for which the main output A is lowest. Now I want to vary the inputs until the outputs b and c meet the constraints. C doesn't reeaally matter since it often meets the constraints, but B (which is stats[1] in the code below) is often too low to be acceptable.

```
inputs = (1, 10, 1.0, 1.0)
stats = qosGenerator(inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2], inputs[3])
count_1 = 0
while stats[1] < 0.999:
  inputs[0] += 0.25
  count_1 += 0.25
  if count_1 == 1:
    inputs[1] += 0.25
  stats = qosGenerator(inputs[0]+1.5, inputs[1]-1.5, inputs[2]-2.5, inputs[3])
```

I started writing this while loop, but I'm struggling to think even in the psuedocode as to how to solve this problem. I'm trying shake each input as little as possible so that the main output remains as close as possible to the local minimum that I found the original inputs for.

Thank you for your input and help!

Comment: Have you considered using the `random` library and just taking a random value from a range to 'shake' the inputs? There almost certainly is an optimisation algorithm that would be more efficient, but if performance isn't a worry you can problem brute force it with randomness.